# Out of memory in jenkins while updating ooxml-schemas jar

Tags: jenkins, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am getting out of memory error while building in jenkins. It happens when poi-ooxml-schemas jar is upgraded. It is being upgraded from 3.6 to 3.12. I checked with 3.13 jar too. It gives the same out of memory error. All other poi jars like poi, poi-ooxml, poi-scratchpad etc are upgraded to 3.12. The moment i update ooxml-schemas jar in my pom.xml and build, jenkins errors out. The same jar has been upgraded to 3.12 in other applications in system.
Below is the stack trace from jenkins

```
[exec]                                                                                Shutting down workbench.
     [exec] Error executing deployment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Error is Java heap space.
     [exec] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
     [exec]     at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.<init>(InflaterInputStream.java:82)
     [exec]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.<init>(ZipFile.java:242)
     [exec]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:242)
     [exec]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:206)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.internal.ArchiveUtil$1.getInputStream(ArchiveUtil.java:254)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.internal.ZipFileArchiveLoadAdapterImpl.getInputStream(ZipFileArchiveLoadAdapterImpl.java:127)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.JavaEEArchiveUtilities$JavaEEWrappingLoadAdapter.getInputStream(JavaEEArchiveUtilities.java:670)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.internal.ArchiveResourceImpl.getInputStream(ArchiveResourceImpl.java:84)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.ComponentArchiveSaveAdapter.save(ComponentArchiveSaveAdapter.java:129)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.AbstractArchiveSaveAdapter.save(AbstractArchiveSaveAdapter.java:71)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.ComponentArchiveSaveAdapter.save(ComponentArchiveSaveAdapter.java:115)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.J2EEComponentArchiveSaveAdapter.save(J2EEComponentArchiveSaveAdapter.java:53)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.internal.ArchiveFactoryImpl.save(ArchiveFactoryImpl.java:114)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.internal.ArchiveFactoryImpl.saveArchive(ArchiveFactoryImpl.java:133)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.J2EEArtifactImportOperation.importModuleFile(J2EEArtifactImportOperation.java:139)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.ejb.archiveoperations.EJBComponentImportOperation.importModuleFile(EJBComponentImportOperation.java:37)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.J2EEArtifactImportOperation.doExecute(J2EEArtifactImportOperation.java:93)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.J2EEArtifactImportOperation.execute(J2EEArtifactImportOperation.java:63)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:376)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:401)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:352)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:242)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:214)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:202)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.EARComponentImportOperation.doExecute(EARComponentImportOperation.java:144)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.J2EEArtifactImportOperation.execute(J2EEArtifactImportOperation.java:63)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:376)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:401)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:352)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:242)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:214)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:202)
     [exec]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension.importEar(BatchExtension.java:1129)
     [exec]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension.runEarDeploy(BatchExtension.java:360)
     [exec]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension$RunDeploy.run(BatchExtension.java:338)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1782)
     [exec]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension$RunDeploy.execute(BatchExtension.java:303)
     [exec]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension.run(BatchExtension.java:266)
     [exec]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [exec]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
     [exec]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
     [exec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:574)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:195)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
     [exec]     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:386)
     [exec]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [exec]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
     [exec]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
     [exec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
     [exec]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.impl.BootLoaderLoader.run(BootLoaderLoader.java:494)
     [exec]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.impl.BatchDeploy.execute(BatchDeploy.java:114)
     [exec]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.execute(EJBDeploy.java:107)
     [exec]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.deploy(EJBDeploy.java:348)
     [exec]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.main(EJBDeploy.java:310)
     [exec] EJBDeploy level: @build@
     [exec] mv: cannot stat `target/ABC_op.ear': No such file or directory
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
```

Comment: I have tried a lot of google search, but none explains the out of memory during jenkins build during ooxml-schema jar upgrade

Comment: `mv: cannot stat target/ABC_op.ear': No such file or directory` here may be you are not using corrent directory or may have permission issue.